# Rust proc macros - how to detect enabled features

Tags: rust, compilation, conditional-compilation, rust-proc-macros

Since Rust proc macro code runs at compile time, I'm assuming what is normally conditional compilation, is accessible at the macro's runtime.

How do I access it? (for example, maybe I only want to parse certain syntax if a given feature is enabled)

For context - what I'm trying to do is parse an identifier - but a conditionally compiled one. My LSP errors out, though actually compiling library consumers works fine.
Closest thing I could find was "CARGO_FEATURE_" in the rust docs, but that's only for build scripts.

Comment: Your proc-macro crate can have features which can be used when executing your macro.

Comment: Perhaps [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58179981/623041) will solve your problem?

Comment: Hey eggyal - this seems to be what I'm looking for, though I don't exactly understand how to do the hack.

Comment: I think I got it, thank you so much!